# I am Unable to find WIFI Driver for Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros

I have LENOVO ideapad310 laptop having two OS in that windows10 & Ubuntu but in that for windows10 WIFI is working properly but when i am booting with Ubuntu their is no driver for that. i visit the lenovo official website bt their is only driver for Windows not for ubuntu.. so what i have to do for installing WIFI driver for Ubuntu???

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035] 
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @-pilot6 after inserting that command it will show this :    sunbeam@tushar:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
 Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
 Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
sunbeam@tushar:~$

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information. Please also add output of `rfkill list` command. And what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: version is 16.04.0

Comment: Sp please post the output of `uname -a`, `dmesg | grep ath` and `rfkill list` TO YOUR QUESTION. You probably need firmware.

Comment: it is not working can you please suggest me third party driver site??

Comment: You already said that it was not working. Can you post the output of the commands, so I can help to sort this out?

Comment: sunbeam@tushar:~$ uname -a
Linux tushar 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
sunbeam@tushar:~$ dmesg | grep ath and rfkill list
grep: and: No such file or directory
grep: rfkill: No such file or directory
grep: list: No such file or directory

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT POST OUTPUT TO COMMENTS. EDIT YOUR QUESTION. It is unreadable here. There are two separate commands `dmesg | grep ath` and `rfkill list`. It is not one command.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`? The firmware may be there already.

Answer (score 3):

You need to connect to the internet by wire and update your system by these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Reboot. The firmware issue should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## sudo apt-get update

## sudo apt-get install git

## git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git

## sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377

## sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0

## cd ath10k-firmware/QCA9377/hw1.0

## sudo cp * /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0

## cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0

## sudo mv firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 firmware-5.bin

If here asking Username & Password for git then download the firmware in compressed format and reconfigure with local path.

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: There is no need to download anything from git anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your driver is  **ath10k_pci**:

As posted in your question.

```
kernel driver in use : ath10k_pci
```

You will find it in:

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k
```

Comment: That's some good information, but how can we use it to help get wireless working?

Comment: you don't have driver problem. your problem is another thing.you should give us more details.for example run `ifconfig`